# Winrar command line not deleting recursive when not using Wildcards

Tags: cmd, winrar

I'm trying to delete some files in a WinRar Archive using the Command Line.

The Rar-File:

```
/testing.rar
/testing.rar/some-data.txt
/testing.rar/testing/some-data.txt
```

Here's my Code:

```
cd "C:\Program Files\WinRAR\" && rar d -cl -r "c:\full\path\testing.rar" some-data.txt
```

It only deletes the some-data.txt file in the root, not inside /testing/

When using

```
cd "C:\Program Files\WinRAR\" && rar d -cl -r "c:\full\path\testing.rar" some-data.*
```

(changed the extension to .*) it does delete both files.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The help page for switch `-r` in help of WinRAR list the commands on which this switch can be used. The command __d__ is not in this list. A wildcard pattern without directory path is applied to all files in archive on using command __d__ independent on directory hierarchy. A wildcard pattern with directory path is applied to all files inside archive on which the entire argument string returns as positive match.

Comment: So, in short, I can't delete recursively without using a Wildcard?

Comment: Yes, that is the short answer. `some-data.txt*` should work, but deletes for example also `some-data.txt1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the `d` command can not handle it, a simple pipe can deal with it

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "rar=C:\Program Files\WinRar\rar.exe"
    set "archive=c:\full\path\testing.rar"

    (
        %= List archive contents =%
        "%rar%" lb -ed "%archive%" 
    )|(
        %= filter the list for the file in any subfolder =%
        findstr /i /e /l /c:"\somedata.txt"

        %= and include the root file =%
        echo somedata.txt
    )|(
        %= Delete from archive the list of files read from stdin =%
        "%rar%" d -cl -n@ "%archive%"
    )
```

The second step (filter the list of files in archive) is splited in the `findstr` and the `echo` just to prevent the case when the file to be deleted is not present in the output. Without a list of files the `-n@` modifier (read files to delete from `stdin`) will not read anything and all the archive contents will be removed.

Answer (score 2):

I looked on first version of great solution of [MC ND](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2861476/mc-nd) and thought by myself what happens if there is by chance although very unlikely a directory with name `some-data.txt` inside the archive?

The answer is that this directory with all files and subdirectories is also deleted because of also listed by `Rar.exe` and `findstr` does not filter out the list entry of the directory as it looks like exactly like a file name entry in bare list format.

The solution for code written by [MC ND](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2861476/mc-nd) is to use the *Rar* command `lb` with switch `-ed` to filter out directory entries on list output. This small modification was applied to the command line by [MC ND](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2861476/mc-nd) in his answer.

Then I thought about using the switches `-ed` and `-x"..."` to filter out directories and file names which should not be deleted on running `Rar.exe` with command `d` and a `some-data.txt` wildcard pattern.

And here is the single line solution:

```
"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\Rar.exe" d -ed -x"some-data.txt?*" -- "C:\full\path\testing.rar" "some-data.txt*"
```

The asterisk at end of file name is necessary to delete all files with name `some-data.txt` inside the archive including the files in subdirectories.

The switch `-ed` excludes all directories in archive including those which by chance are named `some-data.txt`. Directories in archive starting with `some-data.txt` and with more characters appended like a directory with name `some-data.txt_dir`are automatically ignored by `Rar.exe` with used file name wildcard pattern.

The switch `-x"some-data.txt?*"` results in excluding files starting with `some-data.txt` and having more characters appended like `some-data.txt1` and `some-data.txt10`. File names like `first_some-data.txt` are automatically ignored by `Rar.exe` with used file name wildcard pattern.

The switch `-cl` to convert file names to lower case is ignored by *Rar* on using command `d` and therefore not used in the command line above. *Rar* interprets the file names case-insensitive like Windows.

**Update:**

Eugene Roshal, owner of win.rar GmbH, told me by email an easier method to delete a file in root archive folder and in all subfolders:

```
"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\Rar.exe" d "C:\full\path\testing.rar" "some-data.txt" "*\some-data.txt"
```

This command line deletes only `some-data.txt` in root archive folder (last but one argument) and in all its subfolders (last argument). Files in a folder with name `some-data.txt` are not deleted by this command line, but an empty folder with name `some-data.txt` would be also removed from archive. The switch `-ed` can be used additionally to prevent deletion of an empty folder `some-data.txt`.

Comment: Good use of the ? wildcard. My documentation states that -ed switch is used to "do not add empty folders", but after testing it also changes the output of the `l` command.

Comment: @MCND The *WinRAR* documentation contains a help page for switch `-ed`, but in real this switch is just one option of switch `-e` explained in help on page __"-e[+]<attr>" - set file exclude and include attributes__. Switch `-e` with one or more attributes can be used also on all list commands which is not mentioned on help page for this switch.

Comment: I didn't saw the *"In the Windows version..."* and just having the `-ed` documented I didn't keep reading. My fault, thank you.